# PostgreSQL COPY, Is that possible to write data into multiple tables at once

Tags: postgresql, copy, postgresql-copy

I have a bulk dataset which has to be loaded into multiple PostgreSQL tables. Is that possible to accomplish this by using COPY command inside a single transaction? So I can rollback everything if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Begin a transaction inside your SQL and commit it after all COPY statements. If any COPY fails, the whole transaction will be rolled back. For example:

```
BEGIN;

COPY 'FILEPATHINSIDESERVER' TO YOUR.TABLE;
COPY '...' TO ... ;
COPY '...' TO ... ;
COPY '...' TO ... ;

COMMIT;
```